# Htaccess, %{TIME} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} combined

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to set multiple rules based off a set of conditions as follows:

Only apply between 13th April 2016 5am > 11pm.

Only apply if source IP is within range

If both apply, re-direct 2x pages

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20160413050000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20160414230000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.10[3-9] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.11[0-1] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^89\.197\.6\.236
RewriteRule ^confirm.html$ /confirm-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blacklist.html$ /blacklist-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]
```

The time rule works, the IP range works, but when I have multiple blocks of these they seem to conflict. Is the above correct for what im trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more
>   RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. **The following rule** is
>   then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its
>   pattern, and if these conditions are met.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20160413050000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20160414230000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.10[3-9] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.11[0-1] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^89\.197\.6\.236
RewriteRule ^confirm.html$ /confirm-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{TIME} >20160413050000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20160414230000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.10[3-9] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^212\.74\.117\.11[0-1] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^89\.197\.6\.236
RewriteRule ^blacklist.html$ /blacklist-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]
```

Or if you have many rules, reversing the test:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20160413050000 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20160414230000 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^212\.74\.117\.10[3-9]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^212\.74\.117\.11[0-1]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^89\.197\.6\.236
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^confirm.html$ /confirm-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blacklist.html$ /blacklist-logos.html [R=307,L,QSA]
```